# Skiponacci: $p | a_p$ Alternate Solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recursion

For the Skiponacci sequence:

$a_0=3, a_1=0, a_2=2,$ and $a_{n+1}=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ for $n>2$,
prove that any prime $p$ divides $a_p$.

Is there any alternate solution other than using characteristic functions and/or frobenius endomorphism? Such as an elementary solution (no advanced topics please)?

Comment: What is $a$ and $a_p$?

Comment: @QingzhongLiang  I believe the OP means " $p$ a prime $\implies p|a_p$".  At least, that appears to be true for modest $p$.

Comment: The term, "skiponacci", is used for $a_{n+1}=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$. The numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A001608 and many references and links are given. Undoubtedly some answer the question.

Comment: For example, http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath346/kmath346.htm

Comment: Ignoring certain parts of the page, [this page](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/PerrinSequence.shtml) provides a nice combinatorial proof.

Comment: So, Kevin, have you checked any of the links you've been shown?

Answer (score -1):

I will provide a proof based on [this one](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/PerrinSequence.shtml).

Let $S_n$ denote the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}_n = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.
Define a transformation $T$ on $S_n$ by shifting any integer $s \in \mathbb{N}_n$ by $1$:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
    T(s) = s + 1, \quad s<n, \\
    \tau(n) = 1 .
\end{array}\right.$$
Note that $T(S) = S$ is impossible for $S \in S_n$ because, for $s \in S$ that would imply $s + 1 \in S$. For $n = p$, a prime, we may claim that for
$$S \in S_p, T^k(S) = S,\; 1 \leqslant k \leqslant p,$$
only when $k = p$. That is, shifting $S$ repeatedly returns to $S$ only after $p$ shifts. Indeed, let $1 \leqslant k < p$ and $T^k(S) = S$.

Because $p$ is prime, $\gcd(k,p) = 1$ and $p$ so by Bezout's Identity there exist integers $x$ and $y$, with $$xk + yp = 1.$$

Then we know that $k$ shifts, and subsequently $xk$ shifts leave $S$ invariant, as any multiple of $p$ shifts, so that $T(S) = T^{xk + yp}(S) = S$, which is a contradiction.
Therefore, for any $S \in S_p$, the sets
$$S, T(S), T^2(S), \ldots, T^{p-1}(S)$$
are not only distinct but also pairwise disjoint: $T^k(S) \cap T^m(S) = \emptyset$, for $1 \leqslant k, m < p, k \neq m$. In other words, the orbit under $T$ of any $S \in S_p$, consists of $p$ sets so that the whole of $S_p$ splits into subsets of cardinality $p$ each. Therefore, $p \mid \left|S_n\right|$.

Comment: What does this have to do with $a_{n+1}=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The Perrin sequence is prime-divisible which means that for any prime index $p$,$ p \mid P_p$. I gave a proof of this fact.

Comment: I don't see any place in your write-up where you mention, let alone use, the Perrin sequence or its definition.